# JSONKit: create a json formatted string

Tags: ios, json

I want to convert NSDictionary's and NSArrays to json format. Can JSON Kit do that and how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

// data->string

```
NSMutableDictionary *nameElements = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];     

[nameElements setObject:@"abcd" forKey:@"username"];

[nameElements setObject:@"1234" forKey:@"password"];    

NSString* jsonString = [nameElements JSONString];
```

// string->data

```
NSDictionary *nameElements_ = [jsonString objectFromJSONString];   

for(NSString *key in [nameElements_ allKeys]) {
    NSString* body = [nameElements_ objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"%@", body);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**This is an example of sending dictionary and array to server.which worked for me 1000000% .**

```
SBJSON *jparser = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];


NSString *ArrayjsonItems = [jparser stringWithObject:self.UrMergedArray];

NSString *DicjsonItems = [jparser stringWithObject:self.UrMergedDic];




NSLog(@"array Items :%@",self.UrMergedArray);

NSLog(@"dic Items :%@",self.UrMergedDic);




NSString *postString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Arrayitems=%@&Dicitems=%@",ArrayjsonItems,DicjsonItems];


NSLog(@"it is going to post : %@ \n\n",postString);



NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:snapURL];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]
                             initWithRequest:request
                             delegate:self];


if (connection) {

    self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

}


[connection release];
```

Comment: This is supposed to be SBJSON not JSONKit